# shortcut for long command

Tags: bash

#### Problem

I very often have to interact with github which often leaves me writing a line like the following:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:<developer>/<project> <foldername> <maybe_other_args>
```

Now I'd like to minimize this to something like the following (`ghc`=github clone):

```
$ ghc <developer>/<project> <foldername> <maybe_other_args>
```

#### Tried Solutions

My first approach was a function

```
ghc () {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "need to set param: <developer>/<project>"
    else
        git clone git@github.com:$1
    fi
}
```

Neither did I like the verbosity of this approach, nor is it flexible concerning the arguments for `git-clone`.

My second approach was an alias:

```
alias ghc="git clone git@github.com:"
```

But this version doesn't work at all, because after expanding there is a space character between `git@github.com:` and `<developer>/<project>`. I like the shortness of that solution, though. **How to minimize the command with bash, preferably in one line?**

Comment: What about `ghc()` option with multiple params?

Comment: The verbosity of the first approach is mostly caused by the error checking that you don't do it in the second. It wouldn't be so verbose otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error-checking can be done less verbosely in `bash`. But does it really matter how verbose a function's *definition* is, since you will likely add it to a configuration file once and never look at it again?

```
ghc () {
    : ${1?need to set param: <developer>/<project>}
    git clone git@github.com:"$@"        
}
```

One line:

```
ghc () { git clone git@github.com:"${@?need to set param: <developer>/<project>}"; }
```

or without any error

Comment: Thanks. Have also mentioned you in [my .bashrc](https://github.com/erikb85/dot-files/commit/909e1a96031b8d366fa6a24c2cfe8519b1b49cb3) now.

Answer (score 3):

The first approach is perfectly flexible. You just have to learn to use `"$@"` which means all arguments quoted as separate words.

The verbosity in the first case is mostly caused by the error checking. Without it it is just:

```
ghc() { git clone "git@github.com:$@"; }
```

which is only 5 more characters as the (non-working) alias. That will combine first argument with the `git@github.com:` prefix and pass all additional arguments separately just as you wanted.

I don't think the verbosity is a problem when writing it in `.profile` or `.bashrc` though.

Note, that in all other shells (like zsh, but also dash) the function body can be any command, not just compound command, so there the function is exactly as long as the alias:

```
ghc() git clone "git@github.com:$@
```

unfortunately *bash* does not accept this.

Comment: on my system I have to write `ghc(){ git clone "git@github.com:$@"; }` otherwise I always get error messages. Can you guess what might be different on my system?

Comment: The body of a function must be a compound command, so the version in the answer should not work (as it only provides a simple command).

Comment: @chepner: Ok, in _bash_ it indeed has to be compound command. In _all other_ shells it does not have to.

Comment: Since the question is only tagged `bash`, what other shells accept isn't particularly relevant.